# How to mock a nonexistent ActiveRecord model for testing a Rails mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I've taken a quite long time trying to find out a solution how to mock an associated ActiveRecord model, but almost got nothing.

I'm following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#testing-an-engine to build a simple mountable engine. I'm curious how do you do test in this kind of situation, how to mock an associated ActiveRecord model which is only existent in future application?

For example, how to code the test case can make "post = Post.create! valid_attribute" passing?

in post.rb:

```
attr_accessor :author_name
belongs_to :author, class_name: Blorgh.author_class

before_save :set_author

private
  def set_author
    self.author = Blorgh.author_class.find_or_create_by(name: author_name)
  end
```

in test case:

```
  it "assigns all posts as @posts" do
    //how to do here?
    post = Post.create! valid_attributes

    get :index, {use_route: :blorgh}, valid_session
    assigns(:posts).should eq([post])
  end
```

error:

```
  Failure/Error: post = Post.create! valid_attributes
  NoMethodError:
  undefined method `find_or_create_by' for nil:NilClass
```

blorg.rb in blorg\lib direcory

```
  module Blorgh4mRspect
    mattr_accessor :author_class    
    def self.author_class
      @@author_class.constantize
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to keep referencing the `Blorgh.author_class` abstraction instead of hard-coded references to the `User` class?

```
def set_author
  self.author = Blorgh.author_class.constantize.find_or_create_by(name: author_name)
end
```

Comment: oops, I did wrong copy, it's been corrected. I added some more context too for clearing my question.